# Is it possible to change the index order on html with out move the elements?

Tags: html, indexing, calculator

Hello everyOne I have an issue I been trying to change the order of a index(0,1,2...9) without changing the order on html the reason is I want the order of my number like in the image.[Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZZc5.png)

This is another img of the html.

```
<div class="calculator-grid">
<!-- Calculator display  -->
<input type="number">

<!-- Numbers and operator classes -->
<button class="span-two ac-color">AC</button>
<button class="clear-entry">CE</button>
<button class="divideOperator">÷</button>
<button class="number">7</button>
<button class="number">8</button>
<button class="number">9</button>
<button class="multiplyOperator">*</button>
<button class="number">4</button>
<button class="number">5</button>
<button class="number">6</button>
<button class="addOperator">+</button>
<button class="number">1</button>
<button class="number">2</button>
<button class="number">3</button>
<button class="subtractOperator">-</button>
<button class="number-dot definers">.</button>
<button class="number">0</button>
<button class="span-two definers">=</button>
```

So I don't want to change the order of the numbers in the calculator like in the image I want to change the index order for example the html give me number 7 with the index[0] so I want to assign the index[7] to number 7. Can I do that?

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
let inputVar = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function 
(button, index) {
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  input.value += index + 1;
  console.log(inputVar);
});
```

});

Comment: Could you share your current Javascript? You can copy and paste it after formatting instead of sharing pictures.

Comment: if the question you're asking is "why does it post indexed at 0?" that's a standard programming thing, with few exceptions. You'll just have to correct by one, or start your buttons at 0 as well and use css to move the 0 to the bottom/side per standard calculator layout.

Comment: additionally, you could use something like (in PHP) `foreach($input as $key=>$value)` where value is now the number, not the index so you should be able to math off of that.

Comment: @Rojo I add a javaScript.

Comment: @Joshua I don't know php :(.  When I clicked in the button with the number 7 it return me index [1]

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to do it like this:

```
let inputVar = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(button) {
  inputVar[button.innerHTML] = button;
});
```

Set `inputVar` to an empty array and set each element in a loop outside. Use indices from the current button's `innerHTML` and set that index to the current button.

P.S.
`let inputVar = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(` is incorrect. `forEach` should instead be [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: when you say each element into a loop, mean something like this?                              
  for(let i = 0; i < inputVar.length; i++) {
    inputVar[i];
  }                                                                                                                                        
  and how I can set indexes from the current button's?

Comment: @Erick I did everything for you. You can just copy and paste my code. The loop is the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and the indices are from the buttons' [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: sry but this answer doesn't give me the output in the input window like the first one I've sent. Thanks for your help. 

Answer (score 0):

It help to get output in the input window.

```
numberNine.addEventListener('click', function() {
numberNine = Number('9');
input.value = input.value + numberNine;
console.log(numberNine);
```

});

I just use the value property to return the value to the input but it return me a string.